# Como poner y mostrar un archivo html en mi proyecto de android studio?

Tags: android, html, webview

Quisiera que me ayuden con este tema, pues tengo una carpeta con contenido html, en la carpeta está el index.html, la carpeta css, la carpeta de imágenes y todo lo relacionado a la página; quiero mostrar esta pagina en una actividad a través de un WebView, no tengo un ejemplo para mostrar pero vi un proyecto que tenía este en una carpeta Asset; alguien me puede ayudar por favor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitivamente tienes que guardar primeramente tu html o recursos del mismo dentro del folder assets.

Crea el folder, ya que por default no existe:

[image]

Al crear el folder coloca tu html y recursos dentro, es importante que definas las referencias dentro de tu html llamandolas mediante `file:///android_asset` , para cargar el html en un WebView desde assets se realiza de esta forma:

```
 myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myfile.html");
```

Answer (score 5):

Para cargar un html desde assets:

```
WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);  
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

Recuerda que el index.html debe hacer referencias a los demás ficheros (css, js, etc) a través de rutas relativas.

Saludos.