# android studio mostar mesaje de que esta deconetado pero sin mostrar el error por defecto app hibridad

Tags: android-studio, webview

hola soy nuevo tengo la urgencia de crear  un aplicativo para android y bueno lo solucione con un Webview en  android studio 4/java,  y listo pero por casulidad desconete los datos y cuando
inicie la aplicasion que me mostro esto

solo deseo mostrar un simple mesaje como se necesita internet o esta deconetado como soy neofito y solo uso progrmacion web php/mysql/jqueri etc no tengo idea de como se realisa esa comunicasion con en WebView a aplicativo nativo de android yo solo segui los tutoriales paso a paso y me comi mucha informacion en intnet y me costo un mundo,

por ende pido su ayuda

[image: ejemplo]

Answer (score 0):

Considera dos opciones.

**Mostrar Toast al no tener conexión a internet.**

Puedes [validar si existe conexion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/111923/verificar-internet-app-android-studio) y en caso de no existir, mostrar un `Toast`

```
        if (isOnline(getApplicationContext())) { 
    
          //Hay conexión...!

        } else {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"NO hay conexión!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        }
```

Revisa esta respuesta

[Verificar internet App Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/111923/verificar-internet-app-android-studio)

Otra opcion es que al detectar la falta de conectividad cargues una pagina html dentro del `WebView`.

---

**Mostrar pagina web al no tener conexión a internet.**

Primeramente debes crear el directorio `/assets` en tu proyecto y guardar ahí tu archivo `.html` "local", el cual se mostrará cuando no se tenga conexión a internet.

[Como poner y mostrar un archivo html en mi proyecto de android studio?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/82505/como-poner-y-mostrar-un-archivo-html-en-mi-proyecto-de-android-studio)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para detectar conectividad, requieres los permisos:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

---

Este sería un ejemplo, que cargaría el html llamado `mypage.html` almacenado en el directorio `/assets` de tu proyecto en caso de no existir conectividad, de otra forma se mostrará la url `https://es.stackoverflow.com/`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        if (isOnline(getApplicationContext()) {
            //Existe conexion, muestra pagina.
            webView.loadUrl("https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/111923/verificar-internet-app-android-studio");
        } else {
            //*NO EXISTE CONEXION.
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/mypage.html");
        }


    }
```