# Cómo mostrar una página web en caso que no haya internet (WebView)

Tags: java, android, webview

Me gustaría mostrar una página web diferente a la que se carga normalmente en caso de que no haya internet, ya que si desactivo el internet en mi celular y entro a la app me dice que la *página web no es posible cargarla* lo cual daña la imágen de la app porque además muestra el link de la página.

Este es el MainActivity que tengo y pues me gustaría saber qué le agrego para lograr lo que busco.

```
    // MainActivity

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
            WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.loadUrl(""); // SE CARGA LA PÁGINA A MOSTRAR USUALMENTE
            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());
        }
        
        
        
        // MyAppWebViewClient.java
         
        import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

    public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("")) {
                return false;
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Bien, lo que yo haría es crear un archivo `html` y guardarlo en el proyecto. Luego, crear una clase que verifique la conexión de internet. Entonces, cuando se llegue a esa pantalla y no haya conexion se muestre el `html`.

Supongamos que este es tu `html` (prueba.html):

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <h1>Esto es una prueba</h1>
 </body>
<html>
```

Creamos la clase que nos ayudará a corroborar la conexión:

```
public class Conexion {
    public boolean isOnline(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
```

Como complemento, corroboramos tener los siguientes permisos en el Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Siguiendo, crearemos una carpeta para guardar nuestro archivo `HTML`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Visto de otra forma, nos queda así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Update:**

Este sería el `Layout` de la `activity:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipeRefresh"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/pruebaHtml"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Entonces, ahora vamos a la `activity` principal y configuramos el todo (Como plus he añadido un `SwipeRefreshLayout` para controlar la conexión de manera manual):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pruebaHtml = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.pruebaHtml);
    srl = (SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh);

    if(new Conexion().isOnline(MainActivity.this)){
        pruebaHtml.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        pruebaHtml.loadUrl("https://es.stackoverflow.com/");
    }else{
        pruebaHtml.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        pruebaHtml.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/prueba.html");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Se requiere conexión a internet.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    srl.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(new Conexion().isOnline(MainActivity.this)){
                        pruebaHtml.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                        pruebaHtml.loadUrl("https://es.stackoverflow.com/");
                    }else{
                        pruebaHtml.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                        pruebaHtml.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/prueba.html");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Se requiere conexión a internet.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    srl.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            },2000);
        }
    });
}
```

Como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: me da error en estas líneas WebView pageError = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.pageError);
        SwipeRefreshLayout srl = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh);

Comment: Me aparece: Create id value resource

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir tu layout activity a l pregunta?

Comment: He añadido el Layout de la actividad, fijate que tu problema está en que tu layout el id de tus componentes tienen un nombre diferente: **activity_main_webview** He actualizado mi respuesta poniendo el el código de mi layout para que sea más entendible

Answer (score 2):

Para detectar [conexiòn a internet usa el mètodo indicado en esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/3314/95):

```
public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (connectivityManager != null) {
           NetworkCapabilities capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork());
            if (capabilities != null) {
                if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                   // Log.i(TAG, "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR");
                    return true;
                } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                   // Log.i(TAG, "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI");
                    return true;
                }  else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET)){
                   // Log.i(TAG, "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

    return false;

}
```

**Mostrar pagina web al no tener conexión a internet.**

Primeramente debes crear el directorio `/assets` en tu proyecto y guardar ahí tu archivo `.html` "local",

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
 <h3>
  <hr>
  <p><i>página web no es posible cargarla</i></p>
  <hr>
  <h3>
 </body>
<html>
```

el cual se mostrará cuando no se tenga conexión a internet, te sugiero revisar:
[Como poner y mostrar un archivo html en mi proyecto de android studio?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/82505/como-poner-y-mostrar-un-archivo-html-en-mi-proyecto-de-android-studio)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para detectar conectividad, requieres los permisos:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

estos permisos deben ser definidos dentro de tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`.

---

Este sería un ejemplo, que cargaría el html llamado `mypage.html` almacenado en el directorio `/assets` de tu proyecto en caso de no existir conectividad, de otra forma se mostrará la url `https://es.stackoverflow.com/`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        if (isOnline(getApplicationContext()) {
            //Existe conexion, muestra pagina.
            mWebView.loadUrl("https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/111923/verificar-internet-app-android-studio");
        } else {
            //*NO EXISTE CONEXION.
            mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/mypage.html");
        }


    }
```

Comment: Gracias, lo único que me falta es que me digas en que carpeta agrego cada elemento, por lo mismo ya añadí a la pregunta el MyAppWebViewClient.java ya que en esa carpeta vuelve y se llama al link de la página web.

Comment: El archivo html  se debe agregar a /assets , por ejemplo si se llama mypage.html  se cargaría de esta forma :  webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/mypage.html");

Comment: Correcto, pero esta línea? public static boolean isOnline(Context context) en que carpeta va? en la de MyAppWebViewClient?

Comment: el método isOnline puede ir dentro de cualquier clase pero no en MyAppWebViewClient agregala en el mismo nivel de onCreate() de tu Activity, como es "public" puedes llamar el método desde cualquier otra clase,

Comment: Me aparece: Create id value resource

Comment: He cambiado los id y el código de acuerdo a lo que tienes en tu pregunta. Asegura que el Webview con id activity_main_webview se encuentre denteo de activity_main.xml